# How can I tell Puppet to stop a service on shutdown without keeping it running?

Tags: linux, puppet, init

**Context:**

On a linux (RedHat family) system, I have an init-script-based service that is started/stopped manually most of the time, and in general is only run in response to specific, uncommon situations. The init scripts are thin wrappers around code that I do not have control over.

If the service is killed without running the `stop` action on its init script, it is aborted uncleanly and leaves the system in a broken state that requires manual intervention to fix.

When the systems running the service shut down, they kill it uncleanly. I can register the service with `chkconfig` such that it gets shut down via the init script when the host shuts down; this solves the problem on a per-host basis.

**Question:**

I would like to automate the configuration of this service to stop-at-shutdown via Puppet.

How can I tell Puppet to register a service with `chkconfig` such that the service will be stopped via the init script when the system shuts down, but *will not otherwise be managed by Puppet?*

**What I've Tried:**

I made a hokey `exec` statement in Puppet that calls `chkconfig` directly, but that feels inelegant (and will probably break in some way I haven't thought of).

I played around with the `noop` flag to the `service` type in Puppet, but it didn't seem to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet does not have any built-in support for configuring which runlevels a service runs in, nor any built-in, generalized support for `chkconfig`.  Ordinarily it is a service-installation responsibility to register the service with `chkconfig`; services that are installed from the system RPMs are registered that way.

Furthermore, chkconfig recognizes structured comments at the top of initscripts to determine which runlevels the service will run in by default, according to [LSB convention](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/initscrcomconv.html).  A proper initscript need only be registered with chkconfig to have the default runlevels set -- in particular, for it to be set to be stopped in runlevels 0 and 6, which is what you're after.

If you're rolling your own initscripts and deploying them manually or directly via Puppet (as opposed to packaging them up and installing them via Yum) then your best bet is probably to build a defined type that manages the initscript and its registration.  You do not need and probably do not want a `Service` resource for it, but a `File` resource to put the proper file in place and an `Exec` resource to handle registration sounds about right.